# How to mount partition permanently?

Tags: partitioning, mount, automount, gparted

I am using Ubuntu Minimal + LXDE. I am wondering how can I auto-mount a partition (internal) on boot automatically. Currently I do something like

```
mount /dev/sda3 /media/works
```

But I want it to be permanent. Also I have GParted, but the Partition > UnMount is greyed out (yes, unmount, even though I haven't mounted it)

Comment: How does the `mount` command not have a flag to just persist the mount after a reboot? Incredible.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Unmount is greyed out because the partition isn't there to be unmounted. You haven't mounted it yet.

To make the partition auto-mount, first find out the UUID of /dev/sda3 by doing:

```
sudo blkid
```

I'll assume you're using ext4 on /dev/sda3. Open up `gedit` like so:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab
```

(Or, in the command line, `sudo vim` or `sudo nano` instead of `gksudo gedit`.)

Now you want to add a line to the bottom of that file. It should look *something* like this (UUID will be different):

```
UUID=03ec5dd3-45c0-4f95-a363-61ff321a09ff /media/works ext4 defaults  0      2
```

For more info on `fstab`, [this is a good resource](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab).

Comment: I have to mount 2 partitions(sda5 and sda6). Both are ntfs. How can I do it ?

Comment: Is a reboot required?

Comment: A reboot is not reqiured, you can use `mount -a`. Beware that depending on the filesystem type, this may mount it with different user or permissions than what you may need.

Comment: This broke my Debian 11. Could'nt even boot in recovery mode. I had to boot with a Ubuntu USB stick in live mode, and restore the fstab file. which I had saved a copy of before making the changes.

Comment: Did this on a Raspberry Pi, then upon reboot it tried to boot from the newly mounted drive. Didn't even boot after removing the drive. Thankfully this wasn't a laptop, I could just edit the fstab file by removing the SD card. I used `auto` for the fileystem and `nodev,nofail` options and now it works. Also the UUID for me is much shorter (8 chars)

Answer (score 31):

Use Disks utility. Select the disk, then click **Additional partition options** icon. Choose **Edit Mount Options** from drop-down menu.

Comment: This is definitely the simplest way with modern operating systems

Comment: This saved me a lot of time, thank you.

Comment: Amazing man! This is quite helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Ubuntu Server and I made the permanent mount as follows with a disk already formatted in ext4.

I have listed my disks and partitions with

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

After that, I listed the UUID of the partition I would like to mount permanently with the following command:

```
sudo blkid /dev/sda2
```

To mount the partition I created a target location with

```
sudo mkdir -p /home/files
```

then I rode with

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /home/files
```

We need to put the mounted partition in the /etc/fstab file
Don't forget to make a backup first. run

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bkp
```

To avoid breaking the file system you need to look at the structure that is already in `/etc/fstab` for the disks that are already automounted. In my case it is like this

```
sudo cat /etc/fstab

# / was on /dev/sdb3 during curtin installation
# device                                               dir type options  dump fsck
/dev/disk/by-uuid/866f0e5d-e590-450c-beff-507620a4afbd /   ext4 defaults 0     1
```

On the site  [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fstab) it is presented what this structure means. Below is an excerpt:

- `<device>` describes the block special device or remote file system to be mounted; see #Identifying file systems.
- `<dir>` describes the mount directory.
- `<type>` the file system type.
- `<options>` the associated mount options; see mount(8) §FILESYSTEM-INDEPENDENT_MOUNT_OPTIONS and ext4(5) §MOUNT_OPTIONS.
- `<dump>` is checked by the dump(8) utility. This field is usually set to 0, which disables the check.
- `<fsck>` sets the order for file system checks at boot time; see fsck(8). For the root device it should be 1. For other partitions it should be 2, or 0 to disable checking.

Edit the `/fstab` file with

```
sudo vim /etc/fstab
```

or

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

In the file I added the following line

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/6d81205-fc60-44ce-9da2-3565aa /home/files ext4 defaults 0 2
```

Save the file at the end

You can test by restarting the machine

Answer (score 0):

For Booting time mount. you have to provide only auto option. It will work , provide mount id, mount place in your folder, file type, auto, 0, 1.

[image]