# (Lubuntu) How do I make links to folders on my Windows XP hard drive that is already mounted?

Tags: lubuntu

I want to make a shortcut/link to my Windows XP hard drive and put in the documents folder under home/*****.

Answer (score 1):

That's quite easy. Right click on Folder or file and select "make shortcut". Afterwards drag and drop it to the location you want to have it.

The difficulty is, that after reboot the partition won't be loaded again. All your shortcuts will be messed up. You have to mount the partition permanently. See here:

[How to mount partition permanently?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45607/how-to-mount-partition-permanently)

Comment: When I right click my folder (in NTFS partition) there is now option "make shortcut."  I am using Lubuntu, so could this be the problem.  Lubuntu doesn't use Nautilus, it use PCManFM

Comment: Ah, yes, that's true. I can't help you though, as I tried Lubuntu some time ago, and I don't remember. Especially Nautilus is much better than PCManFM and also Thunar from Xubuntu.

Comment: could i get nautilus for Lubuntu?

Comment: I had double install on Xubuntu -Thunar and Nautilus. It is not a good choice to do that, because the desktop environments are closly connected to the file managers. So, I had problems with the Desktop etc. You might try, if it is not availabe from lubuntu-softwarecenter muon, than install it via synaptic. I think there must be a method to make shortcuts in lubuntu.

Comment: Also, if you are working on older hardware, Nautilus will slow down your system. If you are working on new Hardware, install Ubuntu. Lubuntu is lightwight, but because of this reason lacks some features.

Comment: so using PCManFM, there is now way to make shortcuts in Lubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

It is best not to directly read & write into Windows system partitions. Eventually they seem to complain. Most of us suggest a separate NTFS shared data partition. Then you can mount the XP partition as read only in fstab and mount the data partition as read/write. With a permanent mount then you can link the data partition or folders from the data partition into your /home.

Example read only

```
UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /WinC ntfs defaults,noauto,ro,umask=227 0 0
```

For ntfs UUID shown is example only see below:

```
UUID=XXXXXXXXXXX   /media/WinD ntfs defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,uid=1000,windows_names 0 0
```

Window_names prevents the use of invalid windows characters:
(which are the nine characters ” * / : < > ? \ | and those whose code is less than 0×20) 
uid=1000 should fix the trash problems as well:

```
sudo blkid -c /dev/null -o list
sudo mkdir /media/WinD
sudo mkdir /WinC
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.backup
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

And when you are done editing fstab and saving it run the following command to test for errors and mount the partitions without requiring a reboot. You will know before you reboot if something is amiss. Make sure you have partition unmounted if prevously mounted:

```
sudo mount -a
```

Then from your /home you can link a folder in your WinD mount.

ln -s /media/WinD/SomeFolder