# Partition will not mount Automatically

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, mount

The original problem was that a new disk that I installed a month ago, did not mount after a reboot, yes a month later. From Disk UI, I click "mount selected portion" and nothing happens, no error reported. Also, from Disk UI, I click the gears icon, then I click "check Filesystem..."
and it returns "Filesystem Disk_4TB on ST4000DM005-2DP166 is undamaged.".

[devconnected](https://devconnected.com/how-to-mount-and-unmount-drives-on-linux/) provided instructions to mount from the command line.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /Disk_4TB
```

This works fine, so the modified questions are

- Why automatically mount failing given entry in fstab.
- Should I report a bug that the GUI fails to mount and fails to indicate any error code? If so, where do I do this?

[image]
[image]

```
**$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda**
[sudo] password for john: 
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 7814037168 sectors, 3.6 TiB
Model: ST4000DM005-2DP1
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 27569B50-D174-424A-A7BF-4A0E7353C4D9
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 7814037134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 3693 sectors (1.8 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      7814035455   3.6 TiB     8300  Basic data partition
```

$ lsblk -f
NAME                FSTYPE      LABEL        UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
loop0               squashfs                                                              0   100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/95
loop1               squashfs                                                              0   100% /snap/core/10859
loop2               squashfs                                                              0   100% /snap/core/10823
loop3               squashfs                                                              0   100% /snap/core18/1944
loop4               squashfs                                                              0   100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
loop5               squashfs                                                              0   100% /snap/core18/1988
loop6               squashfs                                                              0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop7               squashfs                                                              0   100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
loop8               squashfs                                                              0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
loop9               squashfs                                                              0   100% /snap/microk8s/2035
loop10              squashfs                                                              0   100% /snap/microk8s/2074
loop11              squashfs                                                              0   100% /snap/snap-store/467
loop12              squashfs                                                              0   100% /snap/snapd/11107
loop13              squashfs                                                              0   100% /snap/snap-store/518
loop14              squashfs                                                              0   100% /snap/snapd/11036
sda
└─sda1              ext4        Disk_4TB     c4eaf980-50c9-4c49-9d73-3855be4c91f9
sdb
└─sdb1              ext4        External_2TB a8500ff3-9465-4238-9ada-22ab9ec590ae      1.7T     0% /External_2TB
nvme0n1             ext4        Disk2        16352634-91e0-4567-92cf-065e01395794    757.1G    54% /Disk2
nvme1n1
├─nvme1n1p1         vfat                     112E-F7FA                                 511M     0% /boot/efi
├─nvme1n1p2
└─nvme1n1p5         LVM2_member              4bj3wl-VTM6-f16H-8gXR-bQLV-1Dj0-vtSulI
├─vgubuntu-root   ext4                     f1ab115e-a7b7-4737-b62d-2a6cca1a1016      692G    19% /
└─vgubuntu-swap_1 swap                     1418c65e-e718-49af-a1a5-57f78209480e                  [SWAP]

**cat /etc/fstab**

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme1n1p1 during installation
UUID=112E-F7FA  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0777      0       1
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/16352634-91e0-4567-92cf-065e01395794 /Disk2 auto suid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,auto,exec,rw 0 0
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-BUFFALO_External_HDD_020100005036-0:0-part1 /External_2TB auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/92D6CA0AD6C9EE93 /Disk_4TB auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/c4eaf980-50c9-4c49-9d73-3855be4c91f9 /Disk_4TB auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

---

SOLVED
Wayne observed that /Disk_4TB in fstab had 2 entries with different UUIDs?

I once installed the disk with one of those docking stations before later installed it internally. This creates a second entry in fstab with different UID.

Disk UI did not complain about the conflicting stale entry and succeeded in mounting it the first time around. Subsequent reboots is when this conflict kicks in.

Comment: The gparted output says "Basic data partition" ... are you sure that there are defined a filesystem on it ?

Comment: This disk is for photo backup, no os.  My os is on another disk. I have 100K files on this disk.  I installed it a month ago and using it without issue. Last night I shut down the system for the first time since installing this disk. This morning when rebooted the system, it won't mount.

Comment: Have you tried fsck on that partition? https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Comment: I ran "Check Filesystem" from the GUI. How do I run fsck safely? When I tried fsck -A it say "the filesystem is mounted, if you continue you WILL cause SEVERE filesystem damage?

Comment: updated description because I managed to mount the disk from the command line. Now I need to figure out why it does not mount automatically.

Comment: What does “sudo mount -l -t ext4” show you? Is /dev/sda1 mounted anywhere? If not does “sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt” work, assuming you have a /mnt folder created to mount to.

Comment: Show us your /etc/fstab file. That’s where the automatic mounting at boot time is specified.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mount partition permanently?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45607/how-to-mount-partition-permanently)

Comment: added /etc/fstab

Comment: Looking at the suggested link. The first thing that stands out is that I have an entry for /Disk_4TB and it's the same as /External_2TB that works correctly.

Comment: Isn't /Disk_4TB in fstab twice with different UUIDs?

Comment: wow, I did not see that!!!!

Comment: Wayne, report this as the solution and I will click it as the solution.

Comment: @WayneVosberg See the above comment. :) Grab Bag please note how to notify a specific user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mount point /Disk_4TB is listed in /etc/fstab with two different devices. Only one entry per device/mount point is allowed.

Comment: thank you so much, spent hours looking and failed to see this error.

Answer (score 0):

Wayne observed that /Disk_4TB in fstab had 2 entries with different UUIDs?

I once installed the disk with one of those docking stations before later
installed it internally.  This creates a second entry in fstab with different UID.

Disk UI did not complain about the conflicting stale entry and succeeded in mounting it the first time around.  Subsequent reboots is when this conflict kicks in.