# How to move .julia folder to another partition in Ubuntu?

Tags: disk-usage, chromebook, julia-lang

I use the Julia programming language on a Chromebook with only 32 GB internal storage.

The `.julia` directory in the home folder consumes several gigabytes of space. This directory contains all the julia packages (similar to python libraries), and it is essential for Julia to use those packages.

I have a microSD card with a lot of free space. How do I move the `.julia` directory to the microSD card?

I am using Kubuntu 23.04.

Comment: The same method can be applied to large hidden directories like `.config`, `.cache`, or `.mozilla`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, create ext4 partition in the microSD card (if you already didn't), and configure the partition to be [mounted automatically](https://askubuntu.com/q/45607/124466) at startup. Ensure that you have write access to the ext4 partition (without requiring `sudo`).

For me, that partition is mounted at `/mnt/SDCard/`.

Now, create a directory `julia_dir` in that partition.

```
cd /mnt/SDCard
mkdir julia_dir
```

Now, there are two options. Adding an environment variable, or symlinking (you can use either depending on your choice).

### Method 1

Move the contents of `.julia` to SDCard, and set the environment variable `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH=/mnt/SDCard/julia_dir`

```
mv ~/.julia /mnt/SDCard/julia_dir
echo 'export JULIA_DEPOT_PATH=/mnt/SDCard/julia_dir' >> ~/.bashrc
source .bashrc
```

### Method 2

Move the contents of `.julia` to SDCard, and symlink.

```
mv ~/.julia /mnt/SDCard/julia_dir
ln -s /mnt/SDCard/julia_dir/ /home/your-username/.julia
```

---

Afterwards, Julia would use `/mnt/SDCard/julia_dir/` in the microSD card to store and access its packages.